# Receive data from upper get.json in the get.json below

Tags: javascript, json, itunes, getjson

I'm trying to show the album photo of the song thats on my radio station from the json data of Itunes. However, I can't figure out how to retrieve my radio data from the get.Json data above.

```
function getStreamDetails() {
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
    $.getJSON('https://stream.livexenon.net/api/nowplaying_static/spacenl_radio.json', function (data) {
        var dj = data['live']['streamer_name'] === '' ? 'Auto DJ' : data['live']['streamer_name'];

        $('#dj').html(dj);
        $('#listeners').html(data['listeners']['current']);
        $('#song').html(data['now_playing']['song']['text']);
        song = data['now_playing']['song']['text'];

});

// ALBUM IMAGE
$.getJSON("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term="+song+"&limit=1&media=music&entity=song&callback=?", function (data_foto) {
    var icon = document.getElementById("afbeelding");
    icon.src = data_foto.results[0].artworkUrl100;
});

}

setInterval(getStreamDetails, 10000);
getStreamDetails();
```

Do any have an idea/solution for me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can either move the needed variable out of `getStreamDetails` to the outer scope or move your second `$.getJSON` (which is placed below) to the `getStreamDetails` function. In this case, you will have access to the necessary data.